# Using internal timestep in solving differential equations in R?

Tags: r, differential-equations

I am modelling a [differential-equation](/questions/tagged/differential-equation) where storage (*cm*) depends on in and outflows (*cm/d*) using the [desolve](/questions/tagged/desolve) package in [r](/questions/tagged/r):

*dS/dt = a*In - b*Out*

This works perfect. Now, the problem is to **include a limit on the state variable** storage (*Smax*). If the input - output is larger than what fits in the storage (*Smax*), then *dS/dt* should be set to whatever still fits *(Smax -S)/dt* , so that *S = Smax*.
But here the (internal integrator) timestep *dt* is required. Is there a simple way to retrieve this timestep in deSolve?

A reproducible example of the problem is located below:
The location where a timestep is required is indicated with **### DIVIDE SMAX-S BY TIMESTEP?**

Thanks for your efforts.

```
### dummy data
dtime      <- 1:10 #d
dinput    <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 20, 0)
doutput   <- c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,  0,  5, 0, 0)
dfInput  <- cbind(dtime, dinput)  #cm
dfOutput <- cbind(dtime, doutput) #cm

### input interpolation functions
Input    <- approxfun(dfInput,  rule = 2)
Output   <- approxfun(dfOutput, rule = 2)

### defining initial condition, parameters and time vector
pars      <- c(a=1, b=1, Smax=10) #Smax = maximum storage
times     <- seq(from=0, to=11, by = 0.1)
state_ini <- c(S=2)

### model equations
simple1 <-function(times, state_ini, pars) {
  with(as.list(c(state_ini, pars)),{
    In  <- Input(times)
    Out <- Output(times)

    # calculate rate of change (dS/dt; cm/d)
    dSh <- a*In - b*Out

    # but if storage threshold is exceeded, then fill till maximum storage 
    if(dSh > Smax - S) {dS <- Smax-S} ### DIVIDE Smax-S BY TIMESTEP?
    else {dS <- dSh}

    # return the rate of change
    list(c(dS))
  }) # end with(as.list ...
}


### numerical intergration
out <- ode(y = state_ini, times = times, func = simple1, parms = pars)

### plot result
plot(out, ylim=c(2,10))
```

Comment: quick thought: the `lsodar` function in `deSolve` allows you to do *root-finding*, stopping at a point between reporting times when a specified condition is met.  That might solve your problem ... ?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your quick reply. Checked the lsodar help and think this might indeed do the trick. Will keep this post up to date about the findings.